# How to deal with time consuming python functions in Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have successfully deployed a Django app to Heroku using Postgres. The only problem is that some of the python functions I have written can take up to several minutes to run (data scraping many pages with selenium and generating 50 different deep learning models with keras). If it takes longer than 30 seconds the app crashes. I ultimately plan on using this Heroku app as an API that I will connect to a frontend using React on netlify. Is there a way to automatically run these functions behind the scenes somehow? If not, how can I deploy a website that runs time consuming python functions in the backend and uses React for the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think we can divide the problems in TWO parts:\

1- Heroku free Tier (assuming it is) "kills" the server after 30min of absence ([source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#:%7E:text=CLI%20or%20Scheduler.-,Dyno%20sleeping,free%20dyno%20hours%20while%20sleeping.)), so basically its very difficult to host a backend in heroku. And besides that, since you're training A LOT of deep learning models you could go out of memory and things like that.

2- You might want to redesign your architecture. What about creating a server that once in a while train this machine learning models and the other one just consume and make inferences on those models? You could also separate the scrapping part from the actual server, and just pull data from db.

Since you didn't added constraints to your problem, I see it that way.

Comment: This is great advice thank you very much. I'm also going to look into using fastapi instead of django